# CSS - is it good practice to override an attribute before styling it on the same selector?

Tags: css

I've been meaning to ask this for a while now, for example when overriding the default `hr` look, is it better to do this:

```
hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

Or this:

```
hr {
  border-top: 1px dashed #000;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: I would say there is no real right or wrong here, I personally would use the top example as there is less clutter (and slightly smaller file size) that way, but it's probably a personal preference more than a right or wrong

Comment: Yeah I usually go for the top example, actually I just ran it through the css validator and it validates fine, hmmm but I vaguely remember reading somewhere that had something similar was bad practice

Comment: It not unusual, as this type of overriding is used as a fallback in some cases. For example:
width:50px;
width:5rem;

Rem is not a fully supported unit, so if in IE for example they will not recognize rem, and still use the first declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example:

```
hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
hr {
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border)

So, it could be argued that you're applying a rule to the same property twice, but it's not something to be concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong in both examples, but 1st example has less code so i prefer 1st one.